# Is there a faster way of reading two files line by line, then adding one line at the end of the other?

Tags: python, csv

so here's my problem:

I have two CSV files with each files having around 500 000 lines.

File 1 looks like this:

```
ID|NAME|OTHER INFO
353253453|LAURENT|STUFF 1
563636345|MARK|OTHERS
786970908|GEORGES|THINGS
```

File 2 looks like this:

```
LOCATION;ID_PERSON;PHONE
CA;786970908;555555
NY;353253453;555666
```

So what I have to do is look look for the lines where there are the same IDs, and add the line from file 2 to the end of corresponding line from file 1 in a new file, and if there's no corresponding IDs, add empty columns, like this:

```
ID;NAME;OTHER INFO;LOCATION;ID_PERSON;PHONE
353253453;LAURENT;STUFF 1;NY;353253453;555666
563636345;MARK;OTHERS;;;
786970908;GEORGES;THINGS;CA;786970908;555555
```

File 1 is the primary one if that makes sense.

The thing is I have found a solution but it takes way too long since for each lines of file 1 I loop through file 2.

Here's my code:

```
input1 = open(filename1, 'r', errors='ignore')
input2 = open(filename2, 'r', errors='ignore')
output = open('result.csv', 'w', newline='')

for line1 in input1:
    line_splitted = line1.split("|")
    id_1 = line_splitted[0]
    index = 0
    find = False
    for line2 in file2:
        file2_splitted = line2.split(";")
        if id_1 in file2_splitted[1]:
                output.write((";").join(line1.split("|"))+line2)
                find = True
                file2.remove(line2)
                break
         index+=1
         if index == len(file2) and find == True:
                output.write((";").join(line1.split("|")))
                for j in range(nbr_col_2):
                    output.write(";")
                output.write("\n")
```

So I was wondering if there is a faster way to do that, or if I just have to be patient, because right now after 20 minutes, only 20000 lines have been written...

Comment: That's not even a `csv` format. Anyway, read them as Pandas DataFrames to make the processing, it's way easier this way instead of a manual looping.

Comment: For 500000 lines (not that much) I would directly load file2 lines in memory as a dict.
Then just iterate over file1 and lookup in the dict.

Comment: If ID is the same in file1 and file2, is there a reason to repeat ID 2 times in the output file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read file2 line by line in order to build the `lookup` dict.

Then read file1 line by line, lookup in the dict for the ID key, build the output line and write to the output file.

Should be quite efficient with complexity = O(n).
Only the dict consumes a little bit of memory.
All the file processing is "stream-based".

```py
with open("file2.txt") as f:
    lookup = {}
    f.readline()  # skip header
    while True:
        line = f.readline().rstrip()
        if not line:
            break
        fields = line.split(";")
        lookup[fields[1]] = line

with open("file1.txt") as f, open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    f.readline()  # skip header
    out.write("ID;NAME;OTHER INFO;LOCATION;ID_PERSON;PHONE\n")
    while True:
        line_in = f.readline().rstrip()
        if not line_in:
            break
        fields = line_in.split("|")
        line_out = ";".join(fields)
        if found := lookup.get(fields[0]):
            line_out += ";" + found
        else:
            line_out += ";;;"
        out.write(line_out + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Alex pointed out in his comment, you can merge both files using pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Load files
file_1 = pd.read_csv("file_1.csv", index_col=0, delimiter="|")
file_2 = pd.read_csv("file_2.csv", index_col=1, delimiter=";")

# Rename PERSON_ID as ID
file_2.index.name = "ID"

# Merge files
file_3 = file_1.merge(file_2, how="left", on="ID")
file_3.to_csv("file_3.csv")
```

Using your examples `file_3.csv` looks like this:

```
ID,NAME,OTHER INFO,LOCATION,PHONE
353253453,LAURENT,STUFF 1,NY,555666.0
563636345,MARK,OTHERS,,
786970908,GEORGES,THINGS,CA,555555.0
```

**Extra**

By the way, if you are not familiar with pandas, this is a great introductory course: [Learn Pandas Tutorials](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/pandas)

Comment: This seems very easy to do, but I cannot use pandas unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can create indexing to prevent iterating over file2 each time.
Do this by creating a dictionary from file2 and retrieving each related item of it by calling its index.

```py
file1 = open(filename1, 'r', errors='ignore')
file2 = open(filename2, 'r', errors='ignore')
output = open('result.csv', 'w', newline='')

indexed_data = {}
for line2 in file2.readlines()[1:]:
    data2 = line2.rstrip('\n').split(";")
    indexed_data[data2[1]] = {
        'Location': data2[0],
        'Phone': data2[2],
    }

output.write('ID;NAME;OTHER INFO;LOCATION;ID_PERSON;PHONE\n')

for line1 in file1.readlines()[1:]:
    data1 = line1.rstrip('\n').split("|")
    if data1[0] in indexed_data:
        output.write(f'{data1[0]};{data1[1]};{data1[2]};{indexed_data[data1[0]]["Location"]};{data1[0]};{indexed_data[data1[0]]["Phone"]}\n')
    else:
        output.write(f'{data1[0]};{data1[1]};{data1[2]};;;\n')
```